# Interpolate missing values within groups in Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, group-by, interpolation, missing-data

I have a dataframe that consists of weather data by date on 15 major sites.  So essentially these are 15 multivariate timeseries lumped together in one dataframe.

As there are missing values I would like to fill them through interpolation which makes sense given that they are time series and changes are relatively smooth.

My problem is that I do not know how to do this in Python.  How can I interpolated missing values within each group separately?

Here is a sample of the dataset:

[image]

Comment: Could you post some example data as text instead of image? A good place to start is to run `df.set_index('timestamp').interpolate(method='spline', order=3)` for each value of `site_id`. For more options, [check out the docs on Series.interpolate here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html)

Comment: There is no need to add `Your advice will be appreciated` to the footer of all of your questions. You've probably had ~100 removed by now. Remember that the editors that try to keep this place tidy are volunteers. We may be foolish for taking on the task, but we believe in this community, for all its many faults. We would rather not have to clean up after users who add redundant and conversational material wilfully.

Comment: @Peter Leimbigler:  Thank you Peter, this was my initial inclination.  I wonder though if I could use the groupby method to do everything possibly in one line.  As for the data you can find them here: https://www.kaggle.com/c/ashrae-energy-prediction/data (weather_train.csv)